# How to write a file asynchronously every 30 seconds while another function is running continuously? [Python]

Tags: python, asynchronous

Basically I want to write a file every 30 seconds a function is running.
I tried with async but maybe I'm forgeting something.

Here my code:

```
from time import sleep, time

def print_a():
    while True:
        print("A")
        sleep(5)

def func_write():
    while True:
        with open("/tmp/time.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            f.write(time())
        sleep(30)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_a()
    func_write()
```

Comment: You can use [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Answer (score 0):

Heres the answer:

```
import threading
from time import sleep, time


def write_file():
    while True:
        with open("/tmp/time.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            now = f"{int(time())}"
            f.write(now)
        sleep(5)

def print_a():
    while True:
        print("A")
        sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = threading.Thread(target=write_file)
    x.start()
    print_a()
```